# HTMLCollection's length is 8 but logging any of its indices returns undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop over an HTMLCollection but it appears as though the break-condition is met before the loop is entered. Furthermore, when I print the HTMLCollection to console, it returns the HTMLCollection and I can see that there are elements in it, however, when I try to print any of its indices, it returns `undefined`

Here is the code:

```
var applicant_elements = document.getElementsByClassName('applicant');
console.log(applicant_elements); // returns the HTMLCollection
                                 // with length of 8
                                 // and valid elements
console.log(applicant_elements[0]); // returns undefined
for (var i = 0; i < applicant_elements.length; i++) {
    console.log('hello'); // this is never logged
}
```

Here is what is logged from the above code:

[image: console log screenshot]

I should also state that I am running the following code within an angularJS controller. Not sure if that changes anything, but I feel like it shouldn't

Comment: Is that *really* what your JavaScript looks like? Exactly that?

Comment: The script is most likely placed _above_ the elements in the DOM or before they are available in the DOM. Log the length of the collection and it will be zero.

Comment: Yes, exactly, minus the comments.
That makes sense @Andreas. Indeed, the length is 0. But why would the console log the Collection with all the elements?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444596/why-is-google-chromes-console-delayed), `console.log()` calls are not necessarily immediate in different browsers. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a reference to a **live** HTMLCollection. This means that any changes to the DOM will automatically be reflected in the collection, and thus when the call to console.log is finally resolved, you'll see all of the associated nodes in the output. However, reference to `applicant_elements[0]` is not a live reference - it is resolved at the given point in time and thus will not change from being undefined.

To summarize: your *HTMLCollection* is likely empty right after the query, but your code adds elements before the `console.log()` call is resolved (e.g. before returning from the function).

Comment: Ah. Okay, that makes sense. If I put the code above in `<script>` tags at the end of my HTML, should it work? As is, it doesn't work. NOTHING is logged, not even the collection, or even errors.

**EDIT**
I have a view and an index page. When I put the code in `script` tags at the end of the view's HTML, it logs nothing. At the end of index, it logs the same as the above screenshot.

Comment: It's hard/impossible to say without having more context. From what I can gather, it looks like you're developing an Angular application, so it is definitely possible that those nodes are being rendered asynchronously, whereas the script tags are executed immediately when the HTML is being parsed.

Answer (score 1):

The fun thing with getElementsByClassName is it is a LIVE html collection. So that means things get added and removed from it. And add in the fact you have lazy evaluation in the console, makes for fun debugging.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

console.log("before", x.length);  // will show 0
console.log(x);  // In browser console will show one item because of code below

var d = document.createElement("div");  //create an element to add
d.classList.add("test")  // our class we are looking for
document.body.appendChild(d); // add it

console.log("after", x.length);  // will show 1
console.log(x);  //will show 1 item
```