Socket.io event handler bug
Take a note with onPull event handler. The console.log() is called before textHistory.push(), but the console displays textHistory array with one item inside it, whereas it was an empty array before.
// server.js
import fs from 'node:fs'
import http from 'node:http'
import path from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import chokidar from 'chokidar'
import express from 'express'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import { createServer as createViteServer } from 'vite'

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

let version = 0

async function createServer() {
  const app = express()
  const server = http.createServer(app)
  const io = new Server(server)
  const watcher = chokidar.watch('./note.txt', {
    ignoreInitial: true
  })

  const vite = await createViteServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: 'custom'
  })

  app.use(vite.middlewares)

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  })

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('pull', {
      version,
      data: fs.readFileSync('./note.txt', 'utf8')
    })

    socket.on('push', (data) => {
      fs.writeFileSync('./note.txt', data)
    })

    watcher.on('change', () => {
      version++
      socket.emit('pull', {
        version,
        data: fs.readFileSync('./note.txt', 'utf8')
      })
    })
  })

  server.listen(3000)
}

createServer()

// index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea
      autocapitalize="off"
      class="text-editor text-editor--type-push"
      cols="20"
      id="pushTextEditor"
      rows="10"
    ></textarea>
    <textarea
      autocapitalize="off"
      class="text-editor text-editor--type-pull"
      cols="20"
      disabled
      id="pullTextEditor"
      rows="10"
    ></textarea>
    <div class="push-indicator" id="push-indicator"></div>
    <button disabled id="push">Push</button>
    <button disabled id="pull">Pull</button>
    <p id="length"></p>
    <script src="/main.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>

// main.js
import eruda from 'eruda'
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'
import './style.css'

eruda.init()

const socket = io()

const pushTextEditorElement = document.getElementById('pushTextEditor')
const pullTextEditorElement = document.getElementById('pullTextEditor')
const pushIndicatorElement = document.getElementById('push-indicator')
const pushElement = document.getElementById('push')
const pullElement = document.getElementById('pull')

const textHistory = []
let initialized = false
let isSync
let pushing = false
let pushTimeout
const pushDelay = 1000

function handleInput(event) {
  clearTimeout(pushTimeout)
  pushTimeout = setTimeout(() => push(event.target.value), pushDelay)
}

function push(data) {
  pushing = true
  pushIndicatorElement.classList.add('push-indicator--active')
  textHistory.push({
    version: textHistory[textHistory.length - 1].version + 1,
    data
  })
  socket.emit('push', data)
}

socket.on('connect', onConnect)
socket.on('pull', onPull)
socket.on('disconnect', onDisconnect)

function onConnect() {
  pushTextEditorElement.addEventListener('input', handleInput)
  console.log('connected')
}

function onPull(pullObject) {
  /* bug here */
  console.log(textHistory)

  if (!initialized) {
    initialized = true
    isSync = true
    textHistory.push(pullObject)
    pushTextEditorElement.value = pullObject.data
    pullTextEditorElement.value = pullObject.data
  }
}

function onDisconnect() {
  pushTextEditorElement.removeEventListener('input', handleInput)
}

Here is the project code socket.io-playground
However, if I remove the console.log() and use other display method like writing into the dom with document.getElementById('...').textContent = textHistory.length, it displays 0!

dev tools does that. it has some delay before you can see the output of console.log. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444596/why-is-google-chromes-console-delayed
